# How to handle quarters in d3/crossfilter/dcjs or charting?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a lot of data in dcjs, 450 records in a JSON list, each one has a "mydate" field that contains a specific date. I want to be able to have a bar chart that has quarters "Q1" "Q2" "Q3" "Q4". Is this even possible with dcjs/crossfilter? Or is there some other way to do this with some other charting library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you have a function `dateToQuarter` that takes one or your dates and returns a string "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", or "Q4". (I don't know how you derive your quarters or how your dates are formatted, so I can't give you the actual code.) Then you would:

```
var cf = crossfilter(data);
var quarterDim = cf.dimension(function(d) { return dateToQuarter(d.mydate); });
var quarterGroup = quarterDim.group();
```

Use quarterGroup in your dc.js bar chart.